# Suppose X~Poisson(lamda) and Y~Poisson(sigma) and X and Y are independent. What is the distribution of X+Y?

Tags: statistics

if x and y are independent , the distribution of them would be double Poisson?

Comment: I think any "textbook" that introduces Poisson random variable  would contain this with proof.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_X(n) = \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda}$$
$$g_Y(m) = \frac{\sigma^m}{m!} e^{-\sigma}$$

$$\begin{align}h_{X+Y}(n) &= \sum_{m=0}^{n} f_X(m) g_Y(n-m)\\ &= \sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{\lambda^m}{m!} \frac{\sigma^{n-m}}{(n-m)!} e^{-(\lambda+\sigma)}\\ &= \frac{\sigma^n}{n!}\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m} \left (\frac{\lambda}{\sigma} \right )^m e^{-(\lambda+\sigma)}\\ &= \frac{\sigma^n}{n!} \left ( 1+\frac{\lambda}{\sigma}\right )^n e^{-(\lambda+\sigma)}\\ &= \frac{(\lambda+\sigma)^n}{n!} e^{-(\lambda+\sigma)}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the sum of two independent poisson random variables is also poisson, just add the lambdas for each distribution. In your case, $X+Y\sim Poisson(\lambda+\sigma)$

Comment: If the covariance isn't zero then $X+Y$ can't be poisson.

Comment: But you stated “that that the sum of two poisson random variables is also poisson,” and that's not true in general.

Comment: Done. Thanxalot.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe no problem...always good to have answers stand on their own.

Comment: @user1919987 Please dismiss the downvote, the post as currently written is correct. See http://www.udel.edu/FREC/eggermont/Courses/Stat370/Poisson, which is exactly what Ron Gordon demonstrated below as well.